# Updating certain attributes of an object in Dynamo

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a DynamoDB table `Policies` and the object inside the table is as `pages`. The schema of `pages` looks like this -

```
{
    "pages": {
      "default": [
       {
        "label": "Blocked",
        "bodyMessage": "This content is restricted by your organisation.",
        "pageId": "defaultblocked",
        "pageTitle": "Content Blocked",
        "url": "some.s3.url"
       },
       {
        "label": "Warning",
        "bodyMessage": "This content is not suitable.",
        "pageId": "defaultwarning",
        "pageTitle": "Not Recommended",
        "url": "some.s3.url"
       },
       {
        "label": "Security Risk",
        "bodyMessage": "This content is risky.",
        "pageId": "defaultsecurityrisk",
        "pageTitle": "Risky Content",
        "url": "some.s3.url"
       },
       {
        "label": "Cloud Application",
        "bodyMessage": "This content is risky.",
        "pageId": "defaultcloudapplication",
        "pageTitle": "Cloud Application",
        "url": "some.s3.url"
       }
      ]
     }
}
```

I want to update `pageTitle` & `bodyMessage` of each object of `pages.default` but the values of each object would differ from each other.

For example, object with `pageId` as `defaultblocked` would have values as -

```
{
  "defaultblocked":{
    "pageTitle":"Some title",
    "bodyMessage":"Some message"
  }
}
```

So based on `pageID` the object from the `pages.default` should be selected & the attributes `pageTitle` & `bodyMessage` should be updated.

This is how the entire object would look like -

```
{
  "defaultblocked":{
    "pageTitle":"Some title",
    "bodyMessage":"Some message"
  },
    "defaultsecurityrisk":{
    "pageTitle":"Some title",
    "bodyMessage":"Some message"
  },
    "defaultwarning":{
    "pageTitle":"Some title",
    "bodyMessage":"Some message"
  },
    "defaultsecurityrisk":{
    "pageTitle":"Some title",
    "bodyMessage":"Some message"
  },
    "defaultcloudapplication":{
    "pageTitle":"Some title",
    "bodyMessage":"Some message"
  }
}
```

Comment: So... where's your code? Please show us what you have written.

Comment: @bichanna I am stuck on how to write the query to update this. I haven't written code yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating a specific (nested) attribute in an item can be done using the `update_item`-method, specifically using an UpdateExpression like this:

`SET parent.child = :val`
Multiple update attributes can be concatenated in the same fashion.

An example on how you could set the title/message on two pages looks like this:

```
table.update_item(
        Key={"..": ".."},
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
            "#p": "pages",
            "#blocked": "defaultblocked",
            "#sec": "defaultsecurityrisk",
            "#title": "pageTitle",},
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ":val1": "title of blocked page",
            ":val2": "message on blocked page",
            ":val3": "title of security page",
            ":val4": "message on security page",
        },
        UpdateExpression="SET #p.#blocked.#title = :val1, #p.#blocked.#msg = :val2, #p.#sec.#title = :val3, #p.#sec.#msg = :val4",
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW",
    )
```

Mind the `ExpressionAttributeNames` and `ExpressionAttributeValues`. The names always have to start with a `#`, and the values always start with a `:`. This is a DynamoDB convention to simplify the UpdateExpression, make it easier to read and make it less error prone.

Extending this to include all pages should be trivial, just add the pages to the UpdateExpression and include the values in the ExpressionAttributeNames/Values.

---

**Edit**:
One caveat of this approach, is that you can only update items of a map that already exist.
For your case, if the existing item does not have a specific page yet, it cannot be updated like this.

To add a new page inside the object, you have to specify the entire object as a value:

```
table.update_item(
    Key={...},
    ExpressionAttributeNames={
        "#p": "pages",
        "#blocked": "defaultblocked",
        "#sec": "defaultsecurityrisk",
        "#title": "pageTitle",
        "#msg": "bodyMessage",
        "#new": "newpage"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ":val1": "title of blocked page",
        ":val2": "message on blocked page",
        ":val3": "title of security page",
        ":val4": "message on security page",
        ":new": {"pageTitle": "new title", "bodyMessage": "page of new body"}
    },
    UpdateExpression="SET #p.#new = :new, #p.#blocked.#title = :val1, #p.#blocked.#msg = :val2, #p.#sec.#title = :val3, #p.#sec.#msg = :val4",
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW",
)
```

Comment: #sec & #blocked is not a path it is inside the same object I want to update. This doesn't work.

Comment: I've just updated my answer. This exact code runs fine for me against Dynamo.

Comment: The nested notation is DynamoDB's way of updating items within an object